# Animated GIF in R losing 3 ms in each interval

Tags: r, animation, animated-gif

I'm creating an animated GIF using R's `animation` library. The following code gives an example.

```
library(animation)
saveGIF({
  par(bg=rgb(0,0,0),mar=c(0,0,0,0))
  for (i in 1:30) {
    plot(NULL,xlim=c(-1,1),ylim=c(-1,1))
    ang <- pi*i*12/180
    symbols(cos(ang),sin(ang),circles=1,inches=.2,bg='white',fg=NA,add=T)
  }
},interval=1/30,movie.name='clock.gif',ani.width=500,ani.height=500)
```

The code above produces the image below.

[image: White ball making circles around a black space]

Since `interval` is set to 1/30 (seconds) and there are 30 frames (`i in 1:30`), I would expect that the period of the animation would be closer to 1 second (i.e. each frame should last 33 ms or maybe 33.333 ms if that's possible). However, when I open the image on GIMP, I see that each frame has only 30 ms, instead of 33 or 33.3 ms. What am I doing wrong? Is there any way I can improve this to a precise 1 second in each loop, or at least as close as possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [GIF file format](http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/animation_and_transparency.asp) specifies delay as an unsigned integer indicating delay in "hundredths of a second." It does not have millisecond resolution.

If you want to get closer to 1 second per loop, choose a number of frames that's easily goes into 100 .